# MySQL table proper indexes for performance optimization

Tags: mysql, index

I have a database table (created by someone else). This table consists over billions of records and records are being inserted every second or so.

I need to optimize this table and hence the queries to fetch stuffs faster. Following is the table `ProductCatalog` structure.

```
id                  int(10)
SerialNumber        varchar(20)     
BasePrice           decimal(4,1)    
BatchCode           tinyint(3)
Type                varchar(5)      
ItemCode            varchar(5)      
ArrivalDate         datetime        
InsertTimestamp     int(10)
BrandID             tinyint(3)
CompanyID           tinyint(4)      
Model               varchar(10)     
Description         text
```

Here is the script to create table

```
CREATE TABLE `ProductCatalog` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SerialNumber` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BasePrice` decimal(4,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BatchCode` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ItemCode` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ArrivalDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `InsertTimestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `BrandID` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Model` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'RX209',
  `Description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `SerialNumber` (`SerialNumber`,`ArrivalDate`,`ItemCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here are the sample insert queries.

```
insert into `productcatalog` (`id`, `SerialNumber`, `BasePrice`, `BatchCode`, `Type`, `ItemCode`, `ArrivalDate`, `InsertTimestamp`, `BrandID`, `Model`, `Description`) values('1','345618761','23','25','ACC','ABCD','2021-02-14 12:24:44','1613371259','37','RX209',NULL);
insert into `productcatalog` (`id`, `SerialNumber`, `BasePrice`, `BatchCode`, `Type`, `ItemCode`, `ArrivalDate`, `InsertTimestamp`, `BrandID`, `Model`, `Description`) values('2','345618761','24','25','RAF','ABCD','2021-02-15 12:55:17','1613373031','45','GA317',NULL);
insert into `productcatalog` (`id`, `SerialNumber`, `BasePrice`, `BatchCode`, `Type`, `ItemCode`, `ArrivalDate`, `InsertTimestamp`, `BrandID`, `Model`, `Description`) values('3','569014575','43','21','DAT','TPRS','2021-02-13 12:56:34','1613373082','34','PX452',NULL);
```

There could be many many entries for same `SerialNumber` and `ItemCode`in Different `ArrivalDate`

Initially there were three indexes

```
1. id => Primary
2. SerialNumber
3. ArrivalDate
```

Following are the queries i run against this table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ProductCatalog  
WHERE SerialNumber='1234567890' 
  AND ItemCode!="ABCD" 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1; //This Query Seems slower
    
SELECT BasePrice 
FROM ProductCatalog 
WHERE SerialNumber='123456789' 
  AND ItemCode!="ABCD" 
  and ItemCode!="PQRS" 
  AND ItemCode!="MNOP" 
ORDER BY ID Desc LIMIT 1 //This Query Seems Slower
    
SELECT * 
FROM ProductCatalog 
WHERE SerialNumber='123456789' 
  AND (ArrivalDate>='2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND ArrivalDate<='2020-12-31 23:59:59') 
  AND ItemCode='ABCD' 
ORDER BY ArrivalDate ASC //This query looks ok

SELECT BatchCode
FROM ProductCatalog 
WHERE SerialNumber='123456789' 
  AND ItemCode!="ABCD" 
  and ItemCode!="PQRS" 
  AND ItemCode!="MNOP" 
ORDER BY ID Desc LIMIT 1 //This Query Seems Slower
```

Then I changed the indexes such that we have only two indexes now. The primary and the composite one.

```
1. id => Primary
2. SerialNumber, ArrivalDate, ItemCode
```

Mysql Information

```
MySQL Version 5.7
Engine: InnoDB
```

Problem

The results are still not that satisfactory.

1. Are the indexes I changed correct to get performance gain?
2. Are the order of `columns` in index Correct?
3. Column `SerialNumber` contains 16 digit numeric value, shall i changed it to `int` instead of `varchar` to gain performance?

Comment: Show table structure as complete CREATE TABLE script, including indices. Show some sample data (2-3 rows).

Comment: @Akina, I have updated OP, thanks

Comment: You may try to improve first 2 queries by creating `(SerialNumber, ItemCode)` index (also try `(SerialNumber, ItemCode, id)`) - but in most cases the unequiation does not allow to use the index effectively.

Comment: How does this question differ from https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/285600/mysql-table-proper-indexes-for-performance-optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"billions of records" and `id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` -- Beware!  That will top out at about 4 billion.

To speed up the inserts, see if you can batch them something liek this:

```
insert into `productcatalog`
    (`id`, `SerialNumber`, `BasePrice`, `BatchCode`, `Type`, `ItemCode`,
        `ArrivalDate`, `InsertTimestamp`, `BrandID`, `Model`, `Description`)
    values
    ('1','345618761','23','25','ACC','ABCD','2021-02-14 12:24:44','1613371259','37','RX209',NULL),
    ('2','345618761','24','25','RAF','ABCD','2021-02-15 12:55:17','1613373031','45','GA317',NULL),
    ('3','569014575','43','21','DAT','TPRS','2021-02-13 12:56:34','1613373082','34','PX452',NULL);
```

For the `SELECTs`, then indexes (with the columns in the order specified) should help:

```
INDEX(SerialNumber, ID, ItemCode, BasePrice)  -- for queries 1,2
INDEX(ItemCode, SerialNumber, ArrivalDate)    -- for query 3
```

Query 1 will (I think) use `SerialNumber, ID` from the first index and stop after one or two rows.

Query 2 is "covering", so even it needs to scan several rows, it would have to bounce between the index's BTree and the data's BTree.

Query 3 -- The `=` columns need to be first and the "range" column (`Arrival Date`) last.

The following changes won't improve performance; I just think they are clearer.  Instead of

```
AND ItemCode!="ABCD" 
AND ItemCode!="PQRS" 
AND ItemCode!="MNOP" 

AND (ArrivalDate>='2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND ArrivalDate<='2020-12-31 23:59:59')
```

I prefer these:

```
AND ItemCode NOT IN ("ABCD", "PQRS", "MNOP")

AND ArrivalDate >= '2019-01-01'
AND ArrivalDate  < '2019-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

The following will explain some of my suggestions:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

This seems odd for a "price":  `decimal(4,1)`

Comment: Thanks, so third query should be changed like this this .`..SerialNumber='123456789' AND ItemCode='ABCD' AND (ArrivalDate>='2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND ArrivalDate<='2020-12-31 23:59:59') `. ?  You have added `INTERVAL 1 YEAR`, but in my case the date range is selected by users, it could be any.

Comment: @WatsMyName - True.  If you force the user to type that out, keep the range you describe.  It might help to change the UI to imply >= and <, so as to not force the user to think about, for example "leap year" -- `< 20..--03-01` implies "through February in all cases.

Comment: There is one more select query against this table I missed, please see `4th select query in OP`. Do I need to add one more index like this `INDEX(SerialNumber, ID, ItemCode, BatchCode)`  ? Won't too many indexes slows down the queries?  Do these indexes make any impact on insertion process, when insertion takes place too frequently? Thanks

Comment: It should get reasonable performance out or the first recommended index here as is. Or `BatchCode` could be appended to the first index to gain a covering gain there too as an alternate preference to a new index (its a small column so easy). There's an added insert cost with indexes however usually the query performance gains are usually worth adding them. < 5 non-primary  is probably ok. After that consider, preferably measure, cost and benefits.

Comment: @RickJames with that changes in index you recommended, still a query (`query 3`) is slower first time for particular `SerialNumber` and next execution faster. `ProductCatalog`  has now following indexes `INDEX(ItemCode, SerialNumber, ArrivalDate)` AND `INDEX(SerialNumber, ArrivalDate, ItemCode, BasePrice)`

Comment: @WatsMyName - Running a query on a "cold" system takes longer because of data/indexes needing to be read from disk.

Comment: @RickJames So what is the solution? What else I need to do ?